# Find the coordinates of $\vec{v}$ if $\vec{v}=2\vec{a}-3\vec{b}+4\vec{c}$ and $\vec{a}(4;1),\vec{b}(1;2)$ and $\vec{c}(2;7)$.

Tags: vectors

Find the coordinates of $\vec{v}$ if $\vec{v}=2\vec{a}-3\vec{b}+4\vec{c}$ and $\vec{a}(4;1),\vec{b}(1;2)$ and $\vec{c}(2;7)$.

I am not very familiar with the notation and the way I am supposed to write down such problems. For example, the vector $2\vec{a}$ has coordinates $(8;2)$. Can I write this as $2\vec{a}(8;2)$? Secondly, should I consider the vector $-3\vec{b}$ or $3\vec{b}$? So $-3\vec{b}(-3;-6)$ or $3\vec{b}(3;6)$. Finally, the vector $4\vec{c}$ has coordinates $(8;28).$ Can I write this as $$\vec{v}=2\vec{a}(8;2)-3\vec{b}(...)+4\vec{c}(8;28)$$

Comment: I know the answer is $v =(8,2)-(3,6)+(8,28)=(13,24)  $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, $\vec{u}(p;q)$ means that $\vec u$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^2$, with coordinates $(p,q)$.
So, $$\vec v = 2\vec a - 3\vec b + 4\vec c = 2(4,1) - 3(1,2) + 4(2,7) = (13, 24)$$
In your notation, $\vec v(13;24)$.

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing that by "find the coordinates" it means cartesian coordinates, and that $ \vec{a}(4;1) $ is the same as writing:

$$
\vec{a} = \begin{pmatrix} 4\\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix}
$$

where 4 is the x component, and 1 is the y component. Then you have a vector determined by three others, but, because you are in the plane $ \mathbb{R}^2 $, it is redundant. So you are looking to reduce the number of "coordinates" (numbers by which you label your vector) to two, which is the minimum. As delta-divine has said, the result would be

$$
\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix} 13\\ 24\\ \end{pmatrix}
$$

which is $ \vec{v}(13;24) $ in your notation.